# R apply across rows of data frame

Tags: r, function, loops, apply

[image]
Hi all,
I have a function that has 4 inputs, basically copies files over from one folder into another.

```
tif_copier <- function(file, lane, flipped_cycle, runlink){
  from.dir <- file
  above.dir   <- paste0(runlink, "_flipped\\Images\\L00", lane)
  to.dir   <- paste0(runlink, "_flipped\\Images\\L00", lane, "\\C", flipped_cycle, ".1")
  dir.create(above.dir)
  dir.create(to.dir)
  files    <- list.files(path = from.dir, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
  for (f in files) file.copy(from = f, to = to.dir)
}
testy_t$flipped_cycle <- as.character(testy_t$flipped_cycle)
zzz <- apply(testy_t$tif_files, testy_t$lane, testy_t$flipped_cycle, testy_t$`#runlinks`, 1, tif_copier)
)
```

I can get it to run like this....(input from first row of dataframe)

```
tif_copier(testy_t$tif_files[1], testy_t$lane[1], testy_t$flipped_cycle[1], testy_t$`#runlinks`[1])
```

However, I cannot get it to run against the columns of the dataframe I am scraping the data from.
This is what I have been trying...

```
zzz <- apply(testy_t$tif_files, testy_t$lane, testy_t$flipped_cycle, testy_t$`#runlinks`, 1, tif_copier)
```

I was hoping, someone could explain the correct apply to use, and what the correct syntax would be to loop through each row of the dataframe, testy_t. I thought, apply and using "1", would go through each row, but that is not working. I keep getting...

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'testy_t$flipped_cycle' is not a function, character or symbol
```

I think that means that apply cannot take more than 1 input for its data. Do I need mapply or perhaps lapply?

Comment: (1) Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly. (2) Redacting sensitive data on an image of data generally needs to be full-occlusion, not scratches. I hope it's only "unnecessary" and not truly sensitive, as it's out there now. Please replace it with something we don't have to manually transcribe to be able to help you.

Comment: FYI, `apply` _can_ be used on a `data.frame`, but really it's better suited for `matrix`. Inside of the function passed to `apply`, all of your data will be strings when one or more of them is a string; can't really know based on a picture of your data, but it appears that at least a few of your columns are numeric, not sure if that's an issue. Further, one passes the matrix to `apply` in the first argument only; your second argument `testy_t$lane` is being passed to `MARGIN=`, which isn't going to work. Perhaps your first argument should be something like `testy_t[,c(...)]`?

Comment: Your first 4 arguments in the apply function need to be bundled into a data frame or a matrix of the same data type.

Comment: @r2evans This is true -- part of the reason I didn't want you to recreate the problem, just wanted to ask some question about how apply() works. With as much background as I could provide. I am just asking about how apply() and the other R apply functions work. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Good luck. SO is much more structured towards concrete programming issues, the [tag:r] tag is likely more obsessive about this. This site isn't well suited to be for tutorials or howtos (even if some answers might read that way), so you are more likely to get a prompt and likely detailed response if you make the question more concrete and reproducible. I (personally) am not likely to regurgitate what `?apply` provides, but I am usually quite willing to demonstrate a lot more of its capabilities with a reproducible question.

Comment: So though apply would not work, I did find a solution with mapply! ```zzz <- with(testy_t, mapply(tif_copier,tif_files, lane, flipped_cycle, runlink))```